# Use xstring to replace a macro with different macro

Tags: xstring

### xstring staff...

#### Target

I want to create two labels at beginning and end of specific text respectively.
I have sucessfully writen some code to do this, see the following code:

```
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\hlabel}[1]{\label{#1}\hypertarget{#1}{\linelabel{line:#1}}}

\makeatother
\newcommand{\clab}[2]{%
\protected@write \@auxout {}{\string \newlabel {r:#1}{{#2}{}}}\hlabel{#1}#2\hlabel{#1end}}
\makeatother
```

I can use

```
\clab{lab1}{some text, some text, more text...}
```

to create two lables, which are pointing to the beginning and the end of the text "some text, some text, more text..."

#### Some error

The `\clab{lab}{text...}` function goes wrong if using it like this:

```
  \clab{lab1}{some text, some text, more text..., \clab{lab2}{other text, other text, more other text...}, even more text...}
```

#### My unsuccessful solution

I found some code from a example of [`xstring`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xstring) package (page 18-19)
which could replace the function with another function.
My idea is to replace the inner `\clab{lab2}{text...}` by another empty function `\elab{lab2}{text...}` using the `xstring` package.

First, define pattern and replace function name:

```
\expandarg
\def\pattern{\clab}
\def\replace{\elab}
```

Then, define the two functions `\clab` and `\elab`,

```
 % define a empty function to replace the function \clab
 \newcommand{\elab}[2]{#2}  

 % define a function \clab{label}{texts, texts, blabla}
 \newcommand{\clab}[2]{%
 \protected@write \@auxout {}{\string \newlabel {r:#1}{{#2}{}}}\hlabel{#1}#2\hlabel{#1end}}
```

Finally, I used the xstring package to replace the \clab function by \elab function:

modify the `#2` -----> `\StrSubstitute[2]{#2}{\pattern}{\replace}`

```
\protected@write \@auxout {}{\string \newlabel {r:#1}{{#2}{}}}\hlabel{#1}#2\hlabel{#1end}}
```

It goes like this:

```
\protected@write \@auxout {}{\string \newlabel {r:#1}{{#2}{}}}\hlabel{#1}\StrSubstitute[2]{#2}{\pattern}{\replace}\hlabel{#1end}}
```

### Still wrong, please help!

The executable LaTeX code is here:

### LaTeX code

Please read the following code and help me with the problem

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\hlabel}[1]{\label{#1}\hypertarget{#1}{\linelabel{line:#1}}}

% learn from a example of xstring package (page 18-19, xstring.pdf)
\expandarg
\def\pattern{\clab}
\def\replace{\elab}

\makeatletter
  % define a empty function to replace the function \clab
  \newcommand{\elab}[2]{#2}  

 % define a function \clab{label}{texts, texts, blabla}
  % to create two labels, one is at the beginning of the texts
  % the other is at the end of the texts
  \newcommand{\clab}[2]{%
    % I use the following line to do the job,
    % it is fine to do 
    % \clab{lab1}{texts texts} texts, \clab{lab2}{texts texts} texts, 
    % but it goes wrong with
    % \clab{lab1}{texts texts texts, \clab{lab2}{texts texts} texts}, 
  %\protected@write \@auxout {}{\string \newlabel {r:#1}{{#2}{}}}\hlabel{#1}#2\hlabel{#1end}}
    %so I tried to find the solution,
    % the idea is using xstring function to replace the \clab{lab2}{texts texts texts} by a empty function
    % \elab{lab2}{texts texts texts},
    % I use the following code to do the job, but it still goes wrong!!
    % \expandarg
    % \def\pattern{\clab}
    % \def\replace{\elab}
    % \StrSubstitute[2]{#2}{\pattern}{\replace}
  \protected@write \@auxout {}{\string \newlabel {r:#1}{{#2}{}}}\hlabel{#1}\StrSubstitute[2]{#2}{\pattern}{\replace}\hlabel{#1end}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

THis one not work:
% please uncomment the following line to see the error messages

 % \clab{lab1}{one two three four \clab{lab2}{five six seven eigth} nine ten}.

THis one works:

\clab{lab1}{one two three four}, \clab{lab2}{five six seven eigth} nine ten.

\end{document}
% end of file template.tex
```

Comment: Well, I think you should describe what you want. Having the question at the end of the code is perhaps not the best way?

Comment: Thanks, I have tried my best to make me clear, please help.

Comment: The problem still isn't clear. However, `\StrSubstitute` cannot work inside `\protected@write`, where only expansion can take place, not assignments.

Comment: Could any body help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\hlabel}[1]{\label{#1}\hypertarget{#1}{\linelabel{line:#1}}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\clab}[2]{%
  \protected@write\@auxout{\let\clab\@secondoftwo}{\string\newlabel{r:#1}{{#2}{}}}%
  \hlabel{#1}#2\hlabel{#1end}}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \clab{lab1}{one two three four \clab{lab2}{five six seven eigth} nine ten}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Would you like to expand your answer with some explanation? Code only answer, even if working, don't help readers who may have similar, but not identical, problems.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! Have a look at [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) for a quick intro if you wish to familiarize yourself with our format.

Comment: I don't really know how it works, but it is what i wanted.